# Node JS: Login not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I have used Express on top of Node with .hbs templating. I am using passport to validate the particular user. The database I have used in MongoDB.

Here's my sign-up route:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var passport = require('passport');
var userServices = require('../services/user-services');

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

    var vm = {
    title: 'Join this web',
    };
  res.render('signup', vm);
});

router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
  userServices.addUser(req.body, function(err){
    if(err){
    var vm = {
      title: 'Create an account',
      input: req.body,
      error: err
    };
    delete vm.input.password;
    return res.render('signup', vm);
  }
      req.login(req.body, function(err) {
      res.redirect('/profile');
    });
   });
});
router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'), function(req, res, next){
  res.redirect('/profile');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Here is my login route:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.user) {
    return res.redirect('/profile');
  }
  res.render('login', { title: 'Login' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

I have defined the configuration of of my passport in my passport-congig file:

```
module.exports=function(){
    var passport = require('passport');
    var passportLocal = require('passport-local');
    var userServices = require('../services/user-services');

    passport.use(new passportLocal.Strategy({usernameField: 'email'}, function(email, password, next) {
        userServices.findUser(email, function(err, user){
            if(err){
                return next(err);
            }
            if(!user||user.password!==password){
                return next(null, null);
            }
            next(null, user);
        });
    }));

    passport.serializeUser(function(user, next){
        next(null, user.email);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser(function(user, next){
        userServices.findUser(email, function(err, user){
            next(err, user);
        });
    });
};
```

Also, here is my app.js with passport related code:

```
var passportConfig = require('./auth/passport-config');
passportConfig();

var app = express();

app.use(expressSession({
    secret:'trawel man',
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: false
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

Here is the stack trace of the error that I'm receiving:

```
Error: Not Found

at C:\Users\James\MEAN\app.js:56:15
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\James\MEAN\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:82:5)
at trim_prefix (C:\Users\James\MEAN\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:302:13)
at C:\Users\James\MEAN\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:270:7
at Function.proto.process_params (C:\Users\James\MEAN\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:321:12)
at next (C:\Users\James\MEAN\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:261:10)
at C:\Users\James\MEAN\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:603:15
at next (C:\Users\James\MEAN\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:246:14)
at Function.proto.handle (C:\Users\James\MEAN\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:166:3)
at router (C:\Users\James\MEAN\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:35:12)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\James\MEAN\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:82:5)
at trim_prefix (C:\Users\James\MEAN\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:302:13)
at C:\Users\James\MEAN\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:270:7
at Function.proto.process_params (C:\Users\James\MEAN\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:321:12)
at next (C:\Users\James\MEAN\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:261:10)
at C:\Users\James\MEAN\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:603:15
```

This is what I got at my server console:

`POST /login 404 32.453 ms - 2847`

I have no idea why this isn't working. I am new to Node. Someone help me out.

Comment: Your `deserializeUser` is referencing an undefined variable (`email`). Your strategy handler is not calling `next()` when the user is valid. You're using a variable `pass` which is undefined. It's also unclear how you are connecting Express with Passport. Perhaps you should start with the [`passport-local`](https://github.com/passport/express-4.x-local-example) example if you're new to all of this.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out those errors. I have updated it with the new code. But it still doesn't work.

Comment: I have added the code where I try to connect passport to express, Robert.

Comment: Is not working means that you get an error, it doesn't log you in, login fails...?

Comment: I get an error with the stack trace.

Comment: Please edit the question and add the stacktrace.

Comment: I've added the stack trace. Please have a look.

Comment: That error looks like you have a missing route.  Perhaps /profile ?

Comment: I have the profile route: `var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
 var vm = {
    name : req.user ?req.user.name:null
   };
  res.render('profile', vm);
});
module.exports = router;
`

Comment: Which is the content of app.js at line 56?

Comment: `app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});
`

Comment: Where is `router.get('/profile'...` ?

Comment: `router.get('\profile...') is not necessacary

Comment: @MagicMysteryBro `res.redirect('/profile');` Yes it is...

Comment: @MagicMysteryBro Cant you point to line 56 in app.js?

Comment: Does your other routings work as expected? Do you have line that adds router to the app? (something like `app.use("/", router)`)

Answer (score 4):

```
// process the login form
router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-login', {
    successRedirect: '/',       // redirect to the home page
    failureRedirect: '/login', // redirect back to the login page if there is an error
    failureFlash: true          // allow flash messages
}));
```

This is passport code you should use: (you need to add your user schema path)

```
// load all the things we need
var LocalStrategy    = require('passport-local').Strategy;

// load up the user model
var User       = require('....'); //enter here user path schema

 // load the auth variables


 module.exports = function(passport) {

// =========================================================================
// passport session setup ==================================================
// =========================================================================
// required for persistent login sessions
// passport needs ability to serialize and unserialize users out of session

// used to serialize the user for the session
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});

// used to deserialize the user
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});

// =========================================================================
// LOCAL LOGIN =============================================================
// =========================================================================
passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({
    // by default, local strategy uses username and password, we will override with email
    usernameField : 'email',
    passwordField : 'password',
    passReqToCallback : true // allows us to pass in the req from our route (lets us check if a user is logged in or not)
},
function (req, email, password, done) {
    if (email)
        email = email.toLowerCase(); // Use lower-case e-mails to avoid case-sensitive e-mail matching

    // asynchronous
    process.nextTick(function() {
        User.findOne({ 'local.email' : email }, function (err, user) {
            console.log(user);
            // if there are any errors, return the error
            if (err)
                return done(err);

            // if no user is found, return the message
            if (!user)
                return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'No user found.'));

            if (!user.validPassword(password))
                return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Oops! Wrong password.'));

            // all is well, return user
            else
                return done(null, user);
        });
    });

}));
};
```

EDIT:
I added to you an example to `User` Schema in mongoDB so it will be for you easier to change your code:

```
    // load the things we need
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt   = require('bcrypt-nodejs');


var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    local            : {
        email        : String,
        password     : String
    }
});

// generating a hash
userSchema.methods.generateHash = function(password) {
    return bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(8), null);
};

// checking if password is valid
userSchema.methods.validPassword = function(password) {
    return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.local.password);
};

// create the model for users and expose it to our app
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
//module.exports = userSchema;
module.exports.schema = userSchema;
```

Comment: `var configAuth = require('./auth'); // use this one for testing` is giving an error

Comment: It runs after I have commented it out. But gives back the same error as before.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a route for `/profile` that's why your final "Not Found" route is being called.

Add a route with

```
router.get('/profile', function (req, res, next) {
    var vm = { name : req.user ? req.user.name:null };
    res.render('profile', vm); 
})
```

and that error won't be thrown

EDIT:

Seems like you're getting the error when trying to login, not after. That's because your route for `POST login` is in the wrong file. In your login route file, add the following:

```
router.post('/', passport.authenticate('local'), function(req, res, next){
  res.redirect('/profile');
});
```

(Make sure to import the dependencies)

And remove that `router.post('/login'...` from the signup route.

Comment: Its not working. router.get('/'...) should work because I had created the profile view separately.

Comment: If there's no route for `/profile` then it will go to NotFound, you're redirecting to a route that isn't defined.. Did you try adding the profile route? What error did you get?

Comment: Yes. I did add that extra route. I got the same stack trace as before(I have put it up in the question).

Comment: Did you try adding a console.log in the NotFound route, printing the requested URL?

Comment: You don't have a route for `POST /login` it looks like your login url (for POST) is `/signup/login`

Comment: @MagicMysteryBro I've updated my answer (I've left the previous answer there as I believe it will still be an issue once you get the login working)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98561/discussion-between-magic-mystery-bro-and-slashmanx).

Answer (score -1):

```
import User from "../models/User";
import Role from "../models/Role";

import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
import config from "../config";

//const timer1 = (ms) => new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, ms));
export const signUp = async (req, res) => {

    try {
        // Getting the Request Body
       
        const {
            username,
            email,
            password,
            roles,
            nombres,
            apellidos,
            status,
            telefono,
            cedula,
            foto,
            typo,
        } = req.body;
        // Creating a new User Object
        const newUser = new User({
            username,
            email,
            nombres,
            apellidos,
            status,
            telefono,
            foto,
            cedula,
            typo,
            password: await User.encryptPassword(password),
        });

        // checking for roles
        if (req.body.role) {
            newUser.roles = req.body.role;
        } else {
            const role = await Role.findOne({
                name: "Docente"
            });
            newUser.roles = [role._id];
        }
         
        // Saving the User Object in Mongodb
        newUser.roles = req.body.role;
        const savedUser = await newUser.save();

        return res.status(200).json({
            savedUser
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return res.status(500).json(error);
    }
};
//---------------------------------------------------------LOGIN ACCESS--------------------------
export const signin = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        // EL CUERPO DE CORREO O EL CUERPO DE USERNAME
        const userFound = await User.findOne({
            email: req.body.email
        }).populate(
            "roles"
        );
        //VERIFICAR sI EL USUARIO EXISTE EN BASE DE DATOS
        if (!userFound) return res.status(400).json({
            message: "User Not Found 1"
        });
        //SI EXISTE PASA A VERIFICAR Y DESENCRIPTAR LA CONTRASEÑA
        const matchPassword = await User.comparePassword(
            req.body.password,
            userFound.password
        );
        //RETORNA EL RESULATDO
        if (!matchPassword)
            return res.status(401).json({
                token: null,
                message: "Invalid Password",
            });
        //OPTENERMOS EL ROL
        var toles = null
        const roles = await Role.find({
            _id: {
                $in: userFound.roles
            }
        });
        for (let i = 0; i < roles.length; i++) {
            toles = roles[i].name
            console.log(roles[i].name)
            
        }

        const token = jwt.sign({
            id: userFound._id,
            name: userFound.apellidos+" "+ userFound.nombres,//username
            email: userFound.email,
            foto: userFound.foto,
            role: toles
        }, config.SECRET, {
            expiresIn: 86400, // 24 hours
        });

        res.json({
            token
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
};

//ctl

import { Router } from "express";
const router = Router();

import * as authCtrl from "../controllers/auth.controller";
import { verifySignup } from "../middlewares";

router.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "x-access-token, Origin, Content-Type, Accept"
  );
  next();
});

router.post(
  "/signup",
  [verifySignup.checkDuplicateUsernameOrEmail, verifySignup.checkRolesExisted],
  authCtrl.signUp
);

router.post("/signin", authCtrl.signin);

export default router;
```

Comment: Hi Esteban, welcome to Stackoverflow. You should explain your answer. Pls read [how-to-answer guideline](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)